# How to output Static Code Analyser results to a file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Working on Xamarin Studio, As in Xcode wanted to have a list of Static Code Analyser results. When researched came across this link and it does the analysis well. But I didn't find any list of it as in Xcode. Please suggest me the ways to get the list of the analyser results.

I found [this post](http://joesauve.com/best-kept-secret-in-xamarin-studio-source-analysis-similar-to-resharper/) somewhat useful.